# Git-Bash is Interpolating Environment Variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, git-bash, msys

I'm wondering if someone can explain the following strange behavior:

I have a python script using `os.environ` to pull environment variables for use with `pysftp`. The variable in question has been called "sftp_wd" and "sftp_wdir" with a value "/etc/<rest of path>" and the effect is the same for both.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ["sftp_wdir"]
```

This python code in cmd yields the correct value: `/etc/...`

But when run in git bash the value looks like: `<%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/Programs/Git>/etc/...`

I'm using the same conda environment in both cases and the effect shows up when run in the vscode debugger as well. Additionally if running python with `winpty` I don't see this effect. I've looked at the documentation on `os.environ` and for environment variables used by git bash and not found anything to explain this.

`printenv` also displays the correct value so I'm inclined to believe this is specific to how git bash is initializing python but I can't seem to pin down what's actually happening

**Edit:** In response to @CharlesDuffy it seems this can be replicated with any environment variable and any value starting with "/"
example I created an environment variable called *random* with a value of `/var/`. Results are as follows:

**echo**

```
$ echo $random
/var/
```

**printf**

```
$ printf '%q\n' "$random"
/var/
```

**python**

```
$ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Ana
conda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['random']
'C:/Program Files/Git/var/'
>>>
```

**Note:** The change in the path to the "Git" folder from above is from updating to v2.33.0.2-64bit of Git Bash. The issue is still the same though.

Comment: You're _describing_ the output from the shell, but not _showing_ that output. We need both. Ideally, show the exact output from the command `declare -p sftp_wdir` -- or, to be more robust against values with hidden characters, `printf '%q\n' "$sftp_wdir"`

Comment: BTW, "git bash" is better described as "msys bash". It's not made by the git team or specific to git; msys is the name of the Windows compatibility library it's compiled against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is behavior of msys, the Windows-compatibility library that Git Bash is compiled with. The documentation covering this behavior is at https://www.msys2.org/docs/filesystem-paths/

An environment variable is available to turn it off:

- To turn off automatic path conversion in environment variables entirely, export `MSYS2_ENV_CONV_EXCL='*'`
- To turn it off only for the variable named `random`: `export MSYS2_ENV_CONV_EXCL=random`